# How to add custom property to vue input field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```
<datepicker
            initial-view="year"
            input-class="styled-form__input"
            placeholder="Select date"
            @input="changeHandler"
            calendar-button-icon="fa fa-calendar"
            name="date"
            language="eng"
    ></datepicker>
```

The above code generate the following html code.

```
<input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Select date" class="styled-form__input">
```

My question, how can I add my custom property to the input field.
I would like to add autocomplete="false"

Comment: please share your live demo ?

Comment: Perhaps consider using a solid framework like Quasar which is a component framework for Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [source code](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/fa0e4381c990dd0cc640f7125708d8c8f08773df/src/components/DateInput.vue#L11), at the moment there is no way to add custom properties.
There is a workaround, You can turn off `autocomplete` for all form, but it might not be suitable for your situation.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <datepicker
    initial-view="year"
    input-class="styled-form__input"
    placeholder="Select date"
    @input="changeHandler"
    calendar-button-icon="fa fa-calendar"
    name="date"
    language="eng">
  </datepicker>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @ittus has said, the library does not have the option to add autocomplete.

It can be added through vanilla Javascript.

add a `ref` to the datepicker

```
  <datepicker ref="datepicker1"></datepicker>
```

and query the DOM using the ref in `mounted` hook

```
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.datepicker1.$el.querySelector('input').autocomplete = false;
  }
```